# AngularJs + Angular Material form is submitting twice

Tags: angularjs, forms, form-submit

I'm creating a registration form using AngularJs + Angular Material. Trouble I'm having is that when the form is valid and it is submitted, it is submitted twice. I cannot figure out why.

I'm not declaring the controller twice. The controller is declared only in the route provider.
I'm not using ngSubmit and ngClick simultaneously.

Html code for the form

```
        <form 
            ng-submit="registerForm.$valid && performRegister()" 
            name="registerForm" 
            novalidate>
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="name" 
                    ng-model="register.user.name" 
                    required>
                <div ng-messages="registerForm.name.$error">
                    <div ng-message="required">Inserisci il tuo nome</div>
                </div>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input 
                    type="email" 
                    name="email" 
                    ng-model="register.user.email" 
                    ng-pattern="pattern.emailPattern" 
                    required>
                <div ng-messages="registerForm.email.$error">
                    <div ng-message="required">Inserisci la tua mail</div>
                    <div ng-message="pattern">Devi inserire una mail valida</div>
                </div>
            </md-input-container>
            <p>
                <md-button 
                    type="submit" 
                    class="button-block">Register</md-button>
            </p>
        </form>
```

Controller

```
SOS.controller("RegisterController", ["$scope", "$rootScope", "config", 
function($scope, $rootScope, config) {
    $scope.register = {
        user: {
            name: null,
            email: null, 
        }
    }
    $scope.pattern = {
        emailPattern: config.emailPattern
    }   
    $scope.performRegister = function(){    
        console.log($scope.register.user);
    }
}]);
```

Everytime i submit the form using the submit button, the performRegister() function is called twice, and i see the message in console twice.
If i submit the form using the Enter key it is submitted once.
Any idea why this is happening?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem in my application. This is what I have done to solve it.

I have added 'ng-click="performRegister()" (taking your code as example) in the md-button, & removed the same function from 'form' tag.

So finally it looks like:

```
<form 
        ng-submit="registerForm.$valid" 
        name="registerForm" 
        novalidate>
    ..
    ...
<md-button type="submit" ng-click="performRegister()"
                class="button-block">Register</md-button>
```

Let me know, if this helps.